# C++ - Running one server thread and one client thread in the same program

Tags: c++, multithreading, client-server

I've been trying to modify boost's daytime server/client example to run in 2 threads as below but it didn't work:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
  using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
  time_t now = time(0);
  return ctime(&now);
}

void ServerThread()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13));

    for (;;)
    {
        std::cout << "why?";
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        acceptor.accept(socket);
        std::string message = make_daytime_string();
        boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message),
        boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);
    }

}

void ClientThread()
{
    try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    std::string hostString;

    std::cout << "Please enter the host: ";
    std::cin >> hostString;

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(hostString, "daytime");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  boost::thread s(&ServerThread);
  boost::thread c(&ClientThread);

  c.join();
  s.join();

  return 0;
}
```

The two threads run immediately one after another and will not process correctly. I guess I need to do something along the line of a fork? Please help telling me what's wrong with the code, thank you.

Comment: If you're making a real client/server application, you'll probably save yourself a lot of trouble if you make separate processes for the client and server (instead of separate threads).

Comment: Totally agreed, I was merely playing around with the threading mechanism. Beginner at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client, you left out the section of code that receives the data. Put this in after connect:

```
for (;;)
{
    boost::array<char, 128> buf;
    boost::system::error_code error;

    size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
    if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
        break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
    else if (error)
        throw boost::system::system_error(error);
    std::cout.write(buf.data(), len);
}
```

You'll also need to include boost/array.hpp.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem, I was having a lot of trouble with the errors so I took out the printout section. After more troubleshooting it's working perfectly now :).